# How to subscribe on custom model Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I have got the following custom model:

```
export class CreateEducationYear {

  public year: number;
  public name: string;

}
```

I use this in component like this:

```
public newEducationYearModel: Observable<CreateEducationYear>;
constructor() {
   this.newEducationYearModel = new  Observable<CreateEducationYear>();
}

// Subscribe method

public test(): Observable<CreateEducationYear> {
   return this.newEducationYearModel;
}

// Listening

ngOnInit() {
    this.test().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

I get an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

What do I do wrong?

Template is:

```
{{newEducationYearModel | json }}
<div class="filter-search-item-sub col-md-3">
    <label>Название периода</label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="newEducationYearModel.name" name="period" type="text" value=""/>
</div>
```

After first launch I see `CreateEducationYear {year: 2000}` in console. But further when I change model nothing changes.

Comment: are you trying to mock the result using custom object?

Comment: What are you trying to do? returning observable<CreateEducationYear>() ?

Comment: I try to watch changes in this object, when it is changed in template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you don't need subscriptions. You can use `(ngModelChange)` for your purposes. Change template input:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="newEducationYearModel.name" 
       (ngModelChange)="modelChanged($event, newEducationYearModel)" 
       name="period" 
       type="text" 
       value=""/>
```

And add method to component:

```
public modelChanged(year, newEducationYearModel) {
    console.log('year', year);
    console.log('newEducationYearModel', newEducationYearModel);
}
```

Here is a planker https://plnkr.co/edit/HgzhovgFKczelCr3

Answer (score 1):

Change `test` method to look like:

```
public test(): Observable<CreateEducationYear> {
    return Observable.of(this.newEducationYearModel);
}
```

Comment: I have made changes, but still see nothing in console

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to

```
public newEducationYearModel: CreateEducationYear;
constructor() {
   this.newEducationYearModel = new  CreateEducationYear();
}

// Subscribe method

public test(): Observable<CreateEducationYear> {
   return Observable.of(this.newEducationYearModel);
}
```

And add

```
import "rxjs/add/observable/of";
```

Edit: here is a plunker
https://plnkr.co/edit/KSOSvhe4C1uhTcLc7XML

Comment: I have made changes, but still see nothing in console

Comment: You should have an empty object now. Can you change your constructor by adding: `this.newEducationYearModel.year= 2000;`

Comment: I modify this object from template and see changes in template: {{newEducationYearModel}}, but not in Observel

Comment: Could you update your question with the template, please?

Comment: added a plunker

Comment: Man exactly it works because you click button and just display object model. I dont need that. I dont have button.

Comment: I'm sorry friend but we're asking for help because of this `TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined`. That was because you were not creating the observable. I solved that problem, you can remove the button and put that code on the onInit function and it will still work. If you have a different problem then you must be more clear on the question.

Comment: I will check now

Comment: It does not work, can move to chat? I can not see log.

Comment: I can't have chats yet :)